# How can we achieve throughput greater than 50% of the link rate if wireless radios are half-duplex?

Tags: wireless

Since wireless radios are half duplex, do they divide their time up evenly 50/50 in Tx mode and Rx mode? If so, wouldn't that halve the effective throughput? And yet we are able to achieve throughput greater than 50% of the theoretical link rate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half duplex implies that there is a shared medium (in this case the radio spectrum) that is capable to transport one data flow.

Usually when an host wants to transmit over a shared medium has to run an algorithm to ensure he is the only one that is transmitting to avoid collisions. In the wi-fi world the alghoritm is the [CSMA/CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSMA/CA).

When an host "wins" the channel he transmits at the full bandwidth of the channel.

What you've described better fits in the Time division multiplexing ([TDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing)) that is not really an access method but is a multiplexing one.